# Enabling remote desktop via GPO

Tags: remote-desktop, group-policy

I'm administrating a network of XP SP2 machines, and I would like to enable remote desktop for every one of them. How can I get this done using a GPO?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setting for this in Group Policy is in:

```
Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components ->
Terminal Services -> Allows users to connect remotely using Terminal Services
```

Set to enable to allow terminal services (RDP) connections, disable to disallow.

This assumes that you are using an account to RDP to these machines that is allowed RDP access, such as a member of the administrators group.

Comment: For some reason this did not help..., 
Should this GPO check the box in the System -> Remote Tab -> Allow remote connections?

How can I check if there is a script with higher priority already in my active directory?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah, it should check that box. You can use the resultant set of policy tool to see what policy's are actually being applied - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758010%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: Also keep in mind firewall settings on the clients.  Either windows firewall or a 3rd party.  If you are having trouble connecting once RDP is enabled, you may need to add exceptions or disable them.

Comment: You can use gpupdate to enforce the script on a specific machine.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a VB Script out there That you can run In your GPO->User Configuration->Windows Settings->Scripts(Logon/Logoff). as a Logon script, to enable RDC. Then you would be able to Log in as a Domain admin or with the username that is Running on that Machine.

You are maybe gonna search for a while for such a script and changing it to your needs, but it is worth the trouble. you can use Vb script for almost anything you can click on, it is just a matter of getting the correct script.

Comment: Running a logon script may allow you to enable RDP, but there is nothing to stop the user from disabling it again should they wish. Your better of using GP to set it, so the user cannot override it.